# Powershell to get monitor DPI scaling of ALL monitor

Tags: powershell

Using the DPI class script referenced [here](https://www.osdeploy.com/modules/pshot/technical/resolution-scale-and-dpi) I can get DPI scaling for my main monitor how would I also get the output from any additional monitors which may have a separate scaling factor?

Comment: Is this a UNIX/Linux question?

Answer (score 1):

I am using powershell 7 and i used following code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$rh=[int]((Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Display).ScreenHeight | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String)
$vh=[int][System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen.Height
$screen_scale_factor=$rh/$vh
```

Better still

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms     
# $rh=[int]((Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Display).ScreenHeight | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String)
$rh=[int](Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_VideoController)[0].CurrentVerticalResolution
$vh=[int][System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen.Height
$screen_scale_factor=$rh/$vh
```

And you could iterate over VideoController array and get the same for every monitor.